# How do I set up the ssh private key for webfactory in order to resolve the DuckDuckGO-iOS GItHub Actions error?

Tags: macos, continuous-integration, github-actions, continuous-deployment, cicd

I've forked the DuckDuckGO-iOS repository and [I'm trying to test how the workflows](https://github.com/kgantchev/DuckDuckGo-iOS/pulls) will work with [FlyCI's MacOS runners](https://www.flyci.net/) (M1 and M2 runners).

However, [one of the jobs is failing](https://github.com/kgantchev/DuckDuckGo-iOS/actions/runs/7395945115/job/20120119485?pr=1) with an error:

```
Run webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
Error: The ssh-private-key argument is empty. Maybe the secret has not been configured, or you are using a wrong secret name in your workflow file.
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can set up the secret key and how can I get this repo to build?

Here's is a snippet from the relevant part of my workflow file:

```
    name: Make Release Build

    runs-on: flyci-macos-xlarge-latest-m2
    timeout-minutes: 30

    steps:

    - name: Register SSH keys for access to certificates
      uses: webfactory/ssh-agent@v0.7.0
      with:
        ssh-private-key: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FASTLANE_MATCH }}
```

Comment: As per the error description, it didn't find the SSH private key. Please verify `secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_FASTLANE_MATCH` if it exists.

Comment: I suspect that the secret key would come from the DuckDuckGo iOS repository. Maybe there is a way to circumvent that for the test?

Comment: [With the exception of `GITHUB_TOKEN`, secrets are not passed to the runner when a workflow is triggered from a forked repository.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#using-secrets-in-a-workflow). You may try commenting that [step](https://github.com/kgantchev/DuckDuckGo-iOS/actions/runs/7395945115/workflow?pr=1#L136-L139). Seems like redundant under the release job.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... I reviewed the rest of the build steps and it looks like this whole workflow will not work. I think I'm better off not running it at all.